# How to find the NAT Gateway ID for a specific VPC using the AWS CLI --filter option

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to use the AWS CLI v2.1.22 to find the NAT Gateway ID for a specific VPC using the --filters parameter.  However, I get the following error message:

```
aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --region=us-west-2 --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-0c62e079ca624ac0a"
...
Unknown options: --filters, Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-0c62e079ca624ac0a
```

I verified that the AWS CLI version I am using supports the --filters parameter for describe-nat-gateways. Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: It should be `--filter`, not `--filters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its filter not filters try using the keyword as filter

[image]